# Inverse of $AQ^{-1}A'$

Tags: matrices, inverse, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that $A$ is a $m\times n$ full row rank sparse matrix, and $Q$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite sparse matrix with $m<n$. Besides, $m$ is about $10^5$, and $n$ is about $10^6$. There is no other special structure for $A$ and $Q$ (i.e., not circulant, not Toeplitz, etc.). I need to solve the linear system $AQ^{-1}A'X=B$, where $B$ is an $m\times m$ matrix. Is there any way to find the explicit formula for $(AQ^{-1}A')^{-1}$?

BTW, calculation of cholesky decomposition for $Q$ is not a problem on my laptop, but computing $Q^{-1}A'=L'\backslash(L\backslash A')$ breaks down with out of memory errors in MATLAB. If I compute $Q^{-1}A'$ with parfor loop in MATLAB, it is extremely slow. Direct solvers for these linear systems are preferred.

Thanks,
Pulong

Comment: By $A'$, do you mean the transpose?  Also, why do you prefer direct methods?  If $A$ is sparse, and if you're having memory issues, then Krylov methods could be advantageous.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried several variants myself, I'm convinced that direct methods are not feasible for the typical laptop computer and systems of this size.

You could try the following:

1. Compute $Y = Q^{-1}A'$ via CG (conjugate gradients).  Matlab has a built-in version, `pcg`.  To deal with the multiple right-hand sides $A'$, you can either use a for-loop (which is slow), or see what they do in [A CG Method for Multiple Right Hand Sides and Multiple Shifts in Lattice QCD Calculations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0359).
2. Then compute $(AY)^{-1}B$ via the backslash operator or an LU factorization.  $AY$ will be full. In fact, this is the inherent issue in your problem: you want the inverse of a full matrix $AQ^{-1}A'$. Therefore, you cannot make use of sparse routines at this point.

It's possible step 2 won't work-- for instance, my laptop cannot even store a full array of dimension $10000 \times 10000$.  In which case, you may want to run this problem on a high-performance computer, if your work or campus has one.

**Update:**

You can reformulate your problem as the computation of a bilinear form of a matrix function, $W^Tf(Q)W$, where $W = A^T$, and $f(z) = z^{-1}$.  This form relates to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, which can be approximated by certain quadrature rules.  For how to express $z^{-1}$ as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, see my post [How Can One Write $ {z}^{−1} $ as a Stieltjes Function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317233/how-can-one-write-z-1-as-a-stieltjes-function). I only recently stumbled on this topic myself via the following sources:

1. Chapter 7 in [*Matrices, Moments and Quadrature with Applications*](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9104.html) by Golub and Meurant.
2. [Matrices, moments and quadrature II; How to compute the norm of the error in iterative methods](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02510247) also by Golub and Meaurant.

Comment: 1. Yes, $A'$ standards for the transpose of $A$.
2. $A$ is full-row rank, and it only has explicit formula for its right inverse, say, $A^+$. Then $A^+=A'(AA')^{-1}$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_pseudoinverse .

Comment: Besides, I also have a new idea, but it also does work, see[link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223205-solving-large-linear-system-aq-1-a-x-b).


1.  [R1, p1, s1] = chol(Q, 'vector');

 2.  R1A(s1, :) = R1'\A(:,s1)';  % this step most of the time fails for some Q, with my Mac frozen.

 3.  X1 = factorize(R1A'*R1A)\B; % factorize is  a function in SuiteSparse package.

Comment: You are correct: the left inverses do not exist.  I will either modify or delete my answer.

Comment: I think it is better to always write the name of the sources you link to instead of `Here` or `There`. Someday the links won't be valid, the names will be searchable.